# How can I calculated the weighted mean in the qwraps2 library in R?

Tags: r, summary, weighted-average, qwraps2

I am using the qwraps2 library to produce a summary table. When writing my list of summary statistics, I have:

```
summary1 <-
  list("Wage" =
         list("min"       = ~ min(WAGE),
              "max"       = ~ max(WAGE),
              "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(WAGE)))
```

which is the standard set-up from the manual. However, I would like to calculate the weighted mean and then the standard deviation. Is there a way to do this is qwraps2 or with another command/ library?

**EDIT**

Suppose following dataframe of 5 people, their hourly wage, and their weight in the dataset (for sampling purposes, since I am working with CPS data).

```
library(qwraps2)

person <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
wage <- c(20, 25, 30, 35, 40)
weight <- c(1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3)

dfa <- as.data.frame(cbind(person, wage, weight))
dfa
```

The arithmetic mean (calculated in qwraps2) is 30:
[arithmetic mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7gnp.png)

The weighted mean (which is what I want to calculate in `summary1` is 32.5:
[weighted mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBvik.png)

```
summary1 <-
  list("Wage" =
         list("min"       = ~ min(wage),
              "max"       = ~ max(wage),
              "mean (sd)" = ~ qwraps2::mean_sd(wage)))

output <-summary_table(dfa, summary1)
output
```

Here, the output for the mean is 30 (using qwraps2), which is the arithmetic mean. However, I want the output to be the weighted mean of 32. I hope this helps!

Comment: @akrun I have attached the edits. I hope they help to clear things up

Comment: Why can't you use `"mean (sd)" = ~ weighted.mean(WAGE, weight)))`

Comment: Can you check the solution posted below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `base R` `weighted.mean` which does give the output as expected

```
summary1 <-
  list("Wage" =
         list("min"       = ~ min(WAGE),
              "max"       = ~ max(WAGE),
             "mean (sd)" = ~ weighted.mean(WAGE, weight)))
output <- summary_table(dfa, summary1)
output

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\hline
 & dfa (N = 5)\\
\hline
\bf{Wage} & ~\\
\hline
~~ min & 20\\
\hline
~~ max & 40\\
\hline
~~ mean (sd) & 32.5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! It fixes the issue. I was trying to use qwraps2 because it gives the mean and sd in parentheses. However, I can do that manually/